# Take On, Take Up

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about the confusion between "*take on*" and "*take up*" here:

> 1. "Seeing a stranger with a menacing look, John ***took on*** a fighting stance."
> 2. "Seeing a stranger with a menacing look, John ***took up*** a fighting stance."

Is either "*take on*" or "*take up*" used improperly?

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are informal expressions and have multiple meanings:

*To take on* means:

- to attempt to overcome someone or something (e.g. an obstacle or challenge as @DanTheMan says) - *I'm going to take on the trail today.*
- to assume the duties or responsibilities of something - *I'm taking on the manager's position.*
- to assume a specific demeanor or look - *His face took on a look of disgust.*

*To take up* means:

- to pull or cause to rise upward, particulary with clothing - *Can you take up the dress in the back a little?*
- to clear off or put away - *Take up the dishes from the table*
- to start learning about a skill, hobby, or profession - *Jon took up boxing and has been enjoying it.*

So really *take on* is more appropriate, although *take up* could be used colorfully to express that John is somehow "rising upward" towards the menacing stranger, in a sense.

Also consider [this](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+up+arms):

> take up arms (against someone or something):to prepare to fight
>   against someone or something.
>
> "Everyone in the town took up arms
>   against the enemy. They were all so angry that the leader convinced
>   them to take up arms."
>
> Also, take up the cudgels. Become involved in a conflict, either
>   physical or verbal, as in "The Kurds took up arms against the Iranians
>   at least two centuries ago", or "Some believe it's the vice-president's
>   job to take up the cudgels for the president." The first term
>   originated in the 1400s in the sense of going to war. The variant,
>   alluding to cudgels as weapons, has been used figuratively since the
>   mid-1600s and is probably obsolescent.

Comment: Another colorful interpretation of the "take up" version is that, although he is unarmed, John "took up" his stance as though it were a physical weapon.

Answer (score 0):

"Take up" is correct in this situation.
Take on can be used with some kind of obstacle or challenge, such as "John took on the fighter."